# OpenCV: Get frame by timestamp

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to to get a specific frame from a video by a timestamp. To check if my program works right my video has the recording time in the bottom right corner. Example:

[image]

My problem: If I look for the frame with the timestamp 6000 I get the frame I showed abouth (Which is fine). But if I look for the frame with the Timestamp 60000 I would expect to get the Frame with *20:45:00* **But I get *20:44:54***

I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong, but I can´t figure out what causes this gap of 6 seconds:

Here is my Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/mat.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(const int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int inTimestamp = atoi(argv[2]);

    cv::VideoCapture capture(argv[1]);

    if(!capture.isOpened())
    {
        //error!
        cout << "Can not load video";
    }
    else
    {
        double prevtimestamp = 0;   
        Mat frame;

        while(1)
        {
            capture.grab();
            double timestamp = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);

            if(inTimestamp >= prevtimestamp && inTimestamp <= timestamp )
            {
                    //imshow("Frame",frame);
                    capture >> frame; //new frame   
                    cout << timestamp;
                    imwrite("test.jpg",frame);
                    break;
            }

            prevtimestamp = timestamp;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you check the frame numbers and fps? Maybe with another video editing application like virtualDub?

Comment: @Micka ty for your help! I used vlc to get this information: Codec: MS MPEG-4 Video v2, 640x480, FPS: 5

Comment: opencv gives the same fps and a frame count of 18988

Comment: I meant to count the frames. e.g. at time 20:44:06 (in video) you might have frame nr. x and at time 20:44:26 it should be frame nr. x+20*5 (20 seconds 5 fps). test this for short and for very long durations. Maybe the video was recorded with a little bit more than 5 fps and/or not a perfect 5 fps all the time. Not sure whether vlc can display the frame nr, virtualDub can (and other video editing tools probably too). Initially you could use the frame count, to check whethe the rendered time (duration start to end) and the total number of frames correspond.

Comment: @Micka I checked what you told me but the result looks fine: I have steps of 200 ms between each frame and a timestamp from 6000 gives me frame 30 and a timestamp of 60000 gives me frame 300

Comment: I meant the timestamp that is rendered in the video. And test for a difference of an hour, too.

Comment: I checked the timestamp rendered on the video with avidemux and it really shows for frame 300 at time 1:00 the wrong timestamp. Thank you for your help @Micka

Comment: there might be different reasons for that behaviour. If you are lucky it is a constant factor that you xan multiply on your timestamps (for example if the real recorded fps was 5.5 instead of 5). But those video containers often aren't so good for timestamping recorded data, and/or the timestamps aren't provided correctly.

Comment: it looks like it is not a constant factor: for frame 300 i am 6s off, for 3000 -> 53s and for 18000 -> just 202s